# RoR : You have a nil object you did not expect

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Been Facing this issue,I Have as my view

```
 <%= form_for(:pin, :url => {:action =>"fees"}) do |f| %>
 <%= f.text_field :pin_no %>
 <%= f.submit "Check Pin" , :class => "new_button round" %>
 <% end %>
```

and in my controller i have

```
def fees
@title = "Pay Fees"
pin = Pin.check_pin(params[:pin][:pin_no])
if pin.nil?
  flash.now[:error] = "Pin is not Avaliable"
  render 'fees'
else
  flash.now[:success] = "Pin Avaliable"
end
end
```

in my model, i have a check_pin method defined thus

```
def check_pin(pin_to_check)  
  pin = find_by_pin_no(pin_to_check)
   if pin.nil?
     nil
   else
     pin
    end
  end
```

and i always have this error

```
You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
You might have expected an instance of Array.
The error occurred while evaluating nil.[]
```

what am i missing here please?

Comment: If the exception being raised at the line: pin = Pin.check_pin(params[:pin][:pin_no])?

Comment: Not at all,nothing in my logs either

Comment: All this really says is that there's a `nil` somewhere you didn't expect it. We can't exactly debug it without knowing where it is. The error message should include the line of the file where the error occurred. Please include that—thanks!

Comment: The exception should come along with a stack trace. In the trace there what is the first (top most) file and line number?

Comment: Complain pointed to : pin = Pin.check_pin(params[:pin][:pin_no])

Comment: Still, Havent sorted sorted things out

Comment: Can you post the full error/log excerpt, including the part that lists the parameters being submitted to your controller?

Comment: Peobably you have empty params, check this out. You can also tidy up the code: pin = Pin.find_by_pin_no(params[:pin_no]; if pin else end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get `params[:pin][:pin_no]` only when you post the form so it is giving error `nil.[]` so add `request.post?` to check it only when form is post

```
def fees
  @title = "Pay Fees"
  if request.post?
    pin = Pin.check_pin(params[:pin][:pin_no])
    if pin.nil?
      flash.now[:error] = "Pin is not Avaliable"
      render 'fees'
    else
      flash.now[:success] = "Pin Avaliable"
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

What if you try to simplify it a bit and scrap the check pin method and just do this:

```
def fees
  @title = "Pay Fees"
  if p = Pin.find_by_pin_no params[:pin][:pin_no]
    flash.now[:success] = "Pin: #{p} is Avaliable"
  else
    flash.now[:error] = "Pin is not Avaliable"
    render 'fees'
  end
end
```

Comment: can you post the stack trace? you shouldn't be getting a nil object in this scenario, at least in the controller. could be from whatever you are rendering after. Guessing it is probably in your 'fees' partial when it can't find a matching pin. Are you rendering any kind of object array in 'fees'?

Comment: http://pastie.org/2241675 - Contains the stack Trace while http://pastie.org/2241692 contains modifications made to the controller